# Bump date-based tag in GitHub Actions

Tags: tags, github-actions, versioning

I'm trying to create automatic releases of a [project](https://github.com/Antyos/cascadia-code) using GitHub Actions where the release tag is based on the date. I don't want to use standard semantic versioning because this project is a fork of another project that uses date-based versioning. I've found posts about the getting the date in a workflow and have this so far:

```yaml
name: Publish

on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main ]

jobs:
  publish:
    name: Publish release of font files
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Create foo file
        run: |
          mkdir cascadios
          > cascadios/foo.txt
          
      - name: Get tag name from date
        id: tag_name
        run: echo "::set-output name=date::$(date +'%y%m.%d')"

      - name: Zip font files
        run: |
          cd cascadios
          zip ../cascadios-${{ steps.tag_name.outputs.date }}.zip *
          cd ..

      - name: Create tag
        uses: mathieudutour/github-tag-action@v6.0
        id: tag_version
        with:
          github_token: ${{ github.token }}
          custom_tag: ${{ steps.tag_name.outputs.date }}
```

> Note: I have it creating a blank file to release to save the 15 minutes of building.

This works great until I have two releases in one day (such as today where I am testing this workflow a lot). How can I get it so I can add a dynamic patch number to the tag, so it doesn't cause a conflict? An example might look like `v2112.13.0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use our versioning library - https://github.com/relizaio/versioning

Then you can declare version pattern to be something like: YYYY.0M.0D.Micro

Then the following command would produce a base version:

```
docker run --rm relizaio/versioning -s YYYY.0M.0D.Micro
```

Now, if you already have a version say `2021.12.14.1` and want to bump it up, you would do

```
docker run --rm relizaio/versioning -s YYYY.0M.0D.Micro -v 2021.12.14.1 -a bump
```

This would produce `2021.12.14.2` if you call it on December 14th, or something `2021.12.15.0` if you call this command on the December 15th.

Comment: That's very cool! I had no idea "CalVer" had a name, so that's something to hold on to for later. Is there a way to format such that there is not a separator between the year and month? i.e., `YY0M` for `2112`? I got a RuntimeException when attempting to use `YY0M`.

Comment: Thanks! The library currently mainly relies on separators and we list supported  options in readme, but I guess I could add `YY0M `and `YYYY0M` - should be trivial, will try to commit later today.

Comment: That would be amazing! Thank you!

Comment: Also, although it would likely be a breaking change, it might be worth adding either a "silent" separator (doesn't show in output) or do variable substitution based on `%` like with Linux `date`.

Comment: Should now support YYOM - please give it a try. Regarding silent separators, I'll think about it, but it's going to be a big change. Because separators are actively used currently when we pin versions - i.e. you can set a pin to say 2112.12.Micro - and it would only bump Micro without changing the date (like Ubuntu versioning for example when they release patches). BTW, if you want to keep in touch - feel free to join DevOps Community Discord - https://devopscommunity.org/ - you can always find me there.